# Capture a keypair split & neighbored by fixed values

Tags: regex, awk, grep

Using regex in grep how would I capture the value of `key` **and** `id` (excluding quotes) in:

`<a href="/stats.php?key=string" id="92340" class=""`

---

Best I got with look behind & look ahead is `(?<=<a href="\/stats\.php\?key=).*(?=" class="")` but that results in `string" id="92340`

Ideally the key pair would look like `string 92340`

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following GNU `grep` code. Where I am using `-oP` option to display only matched things and `-P` is for enabling PCRE regex.

```
grep -oP '^<a href="/stats\.php\?key=[^"]*" id="\K\d+'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for used regex.

```
^                       ##Match from starting of the value from here.
<a href="/stats\.php    ##Matching <a href="/stats\.php here where DOT is escaped to make it literal here.
\?key=                  ##Matching literal ? followed by key= here.
[^"]*                   ##Matching everything before next occurrence of " including "
" id="                  ##Match " id=" here as per text.
\K                      ##\K is GNU grep option to forget text what you have mactched till now, match it but don't print it.
\d+                     ##Match 1 OR more occurrences of digits here.
```

To get word string and values also try `perl` better since it has capturing group concept in it.

```
perl -pe 's|^<a href="/stats\.php\?key=([^"]*)" id="(\d+).*$|$1 $2|g' Input_file
```

Comment: I seem to only get the ID part of the key pair with this

Comment: @ClassyUnderexposure, you could use perl one liner as follows `perl -pe 's|^<a href="/stats\.php\?key=([^"]*)" id="(\d+).*$|$1 $2|g' Input_file`

Answer (score 4):

If you want 2 [separate matches](https://regex101.com/r/P4RWQd/1) with grep, you can use the `\G` anchor and make use of `\K` to forget what is matched so far:

```
grep -oP '(?:<a href="/stats\.php\?key|\G(?!^))[^=<>]*="?\K[^<>"]+' file
```

Or matching key and id ([see the matches](https://regex101.com/r/Z7SAUj/1)):

```
grep -oP '(?:<a href="/stats\.php\?|\G(?!^))(?:key=|"\h+id=")\K[^"]+' file
```

Output

```
string
92340
```

Or using `gnu awk` with 2 [capture groups](https://regex101.com/r/InqN0e/1):

```
awk 'match($0, /<a href="\/stats\.php\?key=([^"]*)" id="([^"]*)"/, a) {print a[1], a[2]}' file
```

Output

```
string 92340
```

But if you are free to choose a tool, you could use a dedicated HTML / XML parser as regexes are not aware of any coding structure.

Answer (score 1):

i can't find a solution to implement your requirement only with grep command.
try this:

```
grep -oP '(?<=key=).*?(?=")|(?<=id=").*?(?=")' inputFile | xargs echo
```

[test screenshot(if use grep command only, the output is separated by newline)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5J7B.png)

Answer (score 1):

`grep` is the wrong tool for this, simple substitutions on individual lines like this is exactly the job that `sed` exists to do.

Using any sed in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ sed 's:.*<a href="/stats\.php?key=\([^"]*\)" id="\([^"]*\)".*:\1 \2:' file
string 92340
```